# Declaring an object in a header when its definition is in a different header

Tags: c++

I am new to cpp, looking at an existing project.

There are several places in the project where an object is defined in a namespace in some header file and then declared in the same namespace and used in other declarations in some other header file. Example:

`MyStruct.hpp`:

```cpp
namespace A { struct MyStruct { int i; }; }
```

`MyClass.hpp`:

```cpp
namespace A { struct MyStruct; }

namespace B {
  class MyClass {
  private:
    void foo(A::MyStruct& s);
  };
}
```

`MyClass.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "MyClass.hpp"
#include "MyStruct.hpp"

namespace B {
  class MyClass {
    void foo(A::MyStruct& s) { /* ... */ }
  };
}
```

I might have expected there to be an `#include "MyStruct.hpp"` in `MyClass.hpp`, but that is not the case. I guess when the two header files are isolated there is not yet any relationship between the `MyStruct` objects in that case. Why does this not create some conflict though when the two headers are loaded together in the implementation file? I cannot, for instance, write `int j; int j = 0;`. Does the order of the `#include`s matter? And what might be the motivation for doing this?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if including fields like `struct MyStruct { int i; };` constitutes a definition.

Comment: The order of includes can matter, but a good programmer makes headers that include all of the dependencies they require so that order will not matter (with a few exceptionally rare exceptions where it is impractical to do so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is a [forward declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class) being used.

Since `foo()` takes a `MyStruct` by reference, `MyClass.hpp` doesn't need to know the full declaration of `MyStruct` in order to declare `foo()`, it only needs to know that `MyStruct` exists somewhere.  The linker will match them up later.

`MyClass.cpp`, on the other hand, needs to know the full declaration of `MyStruct` in order for `foo()`'s implementation to access the contents of its `s` parameter.  So `MyStruct.hpp` is used there instead.

This also means that if the contents of `MyStruct.hpp` are ever modified, any source files using `MyClass.hpp` don't have to be recompiled since the forward declaration of `MyStruct` won't change (unless the namespace is changed, that is).  Only files that are using `MyStruct.hpp` will need recompiling, like `MyClass.cpp`.

Answer (score 1):

MyClass.hpp contains a *forward declaration* of MyStruct; it’s just telling the compiler that a type named *struct MyStruct* exists, but not providing any details about what’s in the struct.  That’s enough for things like *const MyStruct &* to compile without syntax errors, but not enough to actually do anything with the struct (since its size and contents are still unknown to the compiler)

As for why someone would do that instead of putting in an #include; it’s a little bit faster to compile, but the main reason would be to avoid cyclic dependencies (eg if MyStruct.h needs to reference MyClass but MyClass.h also needs to reference MyStruct, that would be difficult to achieve using only #include directives)